# Problem opening existing project QT Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm working on QT Creator on Windows and I'm having problem with opening existing project that doesnt have the "Build-**projectname**-Desktop" directory: basically after I select the Kit and press the button "Configure Project" in this view [image: Configure Project] QT Creator get stuck in these status:

[image: load_2]    &     [image: load]

I noticed that if I create a new project I don't have any problems and even if someone else send me the "Build-**projectname**-Desktop" directory the project opens without problems.
So I dont get why it doesnt open and automatically create the directory as it should be.

I already compare my version with my colleagues' and it the exact same (Qt Creator 10.0.1, based on Qt 6.4.3 (MSVC 2019, x86_64)); also uninstall and reinstall with same wizard as them but nothing seems to work.

Can someone help me? I'm stuck like this for a few months now and I tried everything I could think off.

---

Has someone have any clue on how do resolve this? Pls

Comment: Try moving .pro.user file (or equivalent for CMake, I don't remember the name) to backup location before opening the project. If that file is in version control, it shouldn't be.

Comment: Already try that but it didnt change anything. Thks

Comment: Do you get any output in **General messages** or any of the other tabs at the bottom while it's hanging?

Comment: @MihoubAbderrahmeneRayene no output in any tab; the only "Message" I get is **Reading Project "NAME"** as the image in the question. I'm really struggling :(

Comment: Are you using CMake or qmake? And could you show us their files (`CMakeLists.txt` or `.pro`)? Can you make a copy of your project and start trimming it until it works then add back to it gradually to identify what causes it to hang?

Comment: I'm using qmake. But actually it's not just with one project, but multiple projects already existing, so it' gonna be a loooong work to start trimming it and add back for every project. For the .pro file I already confronted with my colleagues' projects or new projects and nothing different